# BitsTransfer , percentage output

Tags: powershell

I want to display the download status in percent.

I use a bitjob for my task.

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a
>   method named 'op_Division'.
>       At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\test.ps1:56 char:8
>       +        $per=$CopyMyBackups.BytesTransferred/$CopyMyBackups.BytesTotal ...
>       +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
>         You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>       At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\test.ps1:57 char:8
>       +        Write-Progress -activity "Copying" -status ($per.ToString()+"% ...
>       +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

My script is below:

```
 }

$BitJobs=Import-Csv "$ScriptPath\$CSVListName" | Start-BitsTransfer -Asynchronous -Priority Normal -DisplayName CopyMyBackups

    while ($CopyMyBackups | ?{ $_.JobState -ne "Transferred"})
    {
       #  this
       $per=$CopyMyBackups.BytesTransferred/$CopyMyBackups.BytesTotal*100
       Write-Progress -activity "Copying" -status ($per.ToString()+"%") -PercentComplete $per

      #$CopyMyBackups = Get-BitsTransfer| ?{ $_.DisplayName -eq "CopyMyBackups"}

       Start-Sleep 10
}  }
$CopyMyBackups| Complete-BitsTransfer
```

Comment: `$CopyMyBackups` is undefined. Read about so-called MCVEs here: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh yeah and your script starts with a closing brace and has one too much at the end

Comment: this is not a complete piece of code, it's still enough

Comment: Exactly, it's **incomplete**.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you start several jobs from CSV, which means that when you try to get `BytesTransferred` property, PowerShell returns an array (`[System.Object[]]`).

You need to iterate over `$CopyMyBackups` or get total of `BytesTransferred/BytesTotal` using something like

```
($CopyMyBackups.BytesTransferred | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

Comment: somehow it is not clear why to do this, I certainly can completely throw the script myself ..
but the point here is that the values ​​if you unload from the jobs there.
which means that the error is just misplaced.
Are there any other ideas?